# Finding the complexity of Loops

Tags: algorithm, big-o, time-complexity, complexity-theory

I'm given this algorithm and I'm told to find the complexity of it big theta.

```
for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    j = n;
    while( j >= 1) {
        j = j/3;
    }

}
```

I know outer for loop runs n times. The while loop is more tricky though, Is it possibly log n (of base 3). In total making it n*log<sub>3</sub>n

Is this correct?

Comment: How did you format it to be of the third base?

Comment: Yes, this is correct. The number of times the inner loop executes is fixed at log n, base 3.

Comment: Press [edit] to find out :-)

Comment: Ahh Okay thank you so nlogn(base 3) works, thanks!

Comment: The (base 3) is wrong. You can convert `log x(base n) = c log x(base m)`. Given that in Theta notation, we drop the coefficient of each term, adding (base 3) is wrong. Therefore the correct form of your answer should be `nlogn`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find time complexity of an algorithm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11032015/how-to-find-time-complexity-of-an-algorithm)

Comment: And on the other hand log(n!) = Θ(n.log(n))

Answer (score 0):

There is an outer for loop of size n. It contributes a complexity of a factor of **n** to the over all complexity.

Let's say inner while loop runs for m times. After i'th iteration, the value of j will be n/(3^i). We will run this till n/(3^i) > 1. Therefore,

```
=> n/(3^i) = m
=> n = 3^m
=> log(n) = log2(3) * m
=> m = O(log(n))
```

So, for loop contributes to O(n) and while loop contributes to O(log(n)). Complexity of nested loop becomes O(n log(n)).